# Emacs tab not working

Tags: emacs, freebsd

I have installed Emacs on my FreeBSD 8.2 box. Everything works fine but I cannot use tabs. When I am editing a file with emacs and hit tab, nothing happens.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What does C-h k TAB tell you ?

Comment: @Bahbar You mean Ctrl - h - k? I don't get it, sorry I'm new to emacs.

Comment: Ctrl-h is the key combo for getting help. then you type k to ask for a keyboard shortcut. Pressing TAB then asks emacs "what is bound to TAB". But never mind. If you're new to emacs, then what you're likely seeing is automatic indenting. Pressing TAB on a line that is already indented will indeed do nothing.

Comment: @RichardKnop: <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd> is the Emacs *help* key. <kbd>Ctrl-h k</kbd> is used to check which command is connected to a specific key. Thus <kbd>Ctrl-h k TAB</kbd> tells you which command you run when you press TAB. Normally this is a command which indents a line according to the major more you are in. If you want to insert a literal TAB character, press <kbd>Ctrl-q TAB</kbd>.

Comment: Ctrl - h doesn't work either. When I press Ctrl - h it works as a delete. It deletes one character.

Comment: What does your ~/.emacs look like?  Do you have something like (global-set-key "\C-h" 'delete-backward-char) in it?

Comment: @jrm Where is the .emacs file located? I tried find / -name ".emacs" with no results. I have installed Emacs from FreeBSD port /usr/ports/editors/emacs.

Comment: Are you running Emacs in a terminal, or using X? (It *sounds* rather like you're running in a terminal, and the codes being sent by the terminal aren't meshing with what Emacs expects. There are ways to resolve that.)

Comment: If you run `emacs -Q` you will bypass any .emacs or site-lisp settings. If you still have the same problem when running Emacs like that, then it's not a problem with those files.

Comment: @RichardKnop, ~/ means your home directory so ~/.emacs means .emacs is in your home directory.  The suggestion to run with the -Q should rule out problems with your configuration.

Comment: This will help with your `C-h` invoking backspace problem: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/efaq.html#Backspace-invokes-help.  This FAQ can be helpful with other problems also.

Comment: I had this issue. I was able to regain use of the tab key by simply closing the file and opening it back up

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you're new to Emacs, you might expect pressing `TAB` to insert a literal `\T`. For various reasons, that's not the way most Emacs modes work. Most editing modes auto-indent your code as needed (`<tab>` is bound to`indent-for-tab-command` rather than `self-insert`). If the line you're `TAB`bing on is already at the correct indentation level, it might seem that nothing happened.

Auto-indenting like this is easier and more consistent than manually indenting, but doesn't give you as much flexibility when it comes to deciding exactly how much whitespace is going to be present at the beginning of each line (and it also causes some problems when you want to, for example, tab-separate some fields). You can auto-indent a region using `C-M-\` (that's `Ctrl + Alt + \`).

If you absolutely, positively must insert a literal `\T` into your code somewhere, you can do so using `C-q TAB` (press and release Ctrl + q and then press TAB). Typically, this is done to align columns in other editors; if that's what you're doing, it's probably a better idea to use `align-regexp` rather than tab literals.

Comment: how do you turn off auto indent then in emacs?

Comment: @user590849 - You probably shouldn't; it takes a bit of getting used to but is much easier thereafter. If you're using a mode with broken auto-indent for some reason, you can just re-bind `<tab>` to `(insert "\t")` in that mode.

Comment: Well, it seems to me Emacs is not that smart to indent all the code. Actually most of time it does not do what you expect. e.g. when you are writing HTML/CSS/Java script in one file and if you just press <tab> on Emacs, it does not work well to indent your HTML/CSS/Javascript code. I have to manually press many spaces to indent my code.

Answer (score 0):

In fundamental and text-mode I use `C-<TAB>`.  I do not know which other modes this works in, but with few exceptions, plain text is the only time I need an actual `\t` character.